# What are some cases, if any, where a button element should act as a link?

Tags: buttons, accessibility, html

Common practice is for links to use the `a` element, and buttons to use the `button` element. But are there any cases (even if their edge cases) where a button, via Javascript, should behave like a link?

Comment: **Should?** I don't know if they should, but its' extremely common. As a matter of fact many of the "buttons" in this page (including the one you used to make this question) are actually `a` elements. Furthermore: I'd bet it's way more common to use `a` disguised as buttons than to use actual buttons (unless you mean something else). Just in case, guess this might be of interest https://accessibleweb.com/question-answer/is-it-ok-to-have-a-link-that-looks-like-a-button/

Comment: @Devin I think he's asking about the opposite case: not `a` styled like a button but `button` functioning like a link.

Comment: Why even question this? No one benefits from mixing up behaviour of buttons and links. It makes it harder to implement, confusing for users and isn't necessary by any means.

Comment: @LukeSawczak yes you're correct. i was unsure hence why I commented, but after your comment and re-reading I see it's like you say :)

Comment: @jazZRo if you are using React and you've setup your components correctly, you change one file and all the relevant items get the changes.

Comment: @KitangaNday Ok, let’s not call it hard to implement but overengineering.

Comment: @jazZRo this isn't true, it's actually the exact opposite. Devs aren't thinking "oh how will this button be recognized as a link", they just pick a button and roll with it. This is why few people know about ARIA and friends.

Comment: *"This is why few people know about ARIA and friends"*.  ???  Few people know about ARIA?  Everybody I know knows about ARIA.  That's a very subjective statement - both yours and mine.  If you want an accessible website, hopefully you're following [ARIA rule #1](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) and using semantic HTML. You can get a lot (sometimes all) of your accessibility that way. If the semantics don't exist in native HTML (such as a tree widget), that's where ARIA fills in the gap. **All** (web) developers should be familiar with ARIA.

Comment: @KitangaNday I get what you're thinking, but that has nothing to do with the question. Using javascript to make a link act like a button while there is a button element to choose from is a form of overengineering. When links and buttons are styled and  handled correctly, using a framework or not, there is no reason to make a link look and function like a button or vice versa.

Comment: @jazZRo it isn't overengineering, I can't think of a single frontend lib that uses a tags as buttons by default. Bootstrap's buttons for example use the button element. Unless you plan on making your designs without the help of a CSS lib

Comment: @slugolicious then you have good friends. None of the programmer's have run by know about ARIA, or that there was a spec for accessibility. There was one guy at our company who recently run into it. Anywho, good friends you have.

Comment: @KitangaNday just because you know people that don’t know ARIA doesn’t mean you have to accept that. Help spread the a11y knowledge. Same with frameworks. Just because they have bad practices doesn’t mean you have to accept it. It just means there are framework employees (or contributors) that need to improve their a11y knowledge. Anti-patterns should be avoided.

Comment: I agree with @jazZRo that it’s overengineered. *Could* you implement a solution using all <div> and <span> elements with lots of ARIA and JavaScript?  Absolutely. *Should* you? I would strongly discourage it. It’s much more code than necessary and thus overengineered. Take advantage of semantic html and get a lot of accessibility for free

Comment: @slugolicious if you get to a company and they have two year old code, with a 2 year old stack and you get in with that mentality, you'll find yourself in the QA department. No company just rewrites there code to fit a minority. I'd rather overengineer a couple of files and give users a good experience than waste time trying to rewrite my code semantically. Not trying to be rude, but this I'm OK with. Tech should always serve UX, not the other way

Comment: @KitangaNday, you almost had me that you might know or care a little bit about accessibility but saying *"No company just rewrites there [sic] code to fit a minority"* showed me how much you *don't* know about accessibility. The disability community is hugely underrepresented and marginalized which is why countries had to create laws to protect them (us). Not everyone has perfect eyesight or hearing or dexterity, and for those that do, it is most likely temporary because life happens, and if you're lucky, you grow old and naturally age into some disabilities. Feel free to respond but I'm done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you tagged this with `accessibility`, I'm answering from that perspective.

**No**

A link is for navigation and implies the browser's "back" button will take you back to the previous page.

A button is for actions, such as "add to cart" (which is actually an interesting case since most "add to cart" buttons, while they do add the product to the cart, they sometimes take you to the cart too so they perform an action *and* navigate you.  But using the browser's "back" button does **not** remove the product from the cart. That's usually a separate **button**).

So from an accessibility perspective, when a screen reader user hears "button", they'll expect to perform some action and the browser's "back" button does not come into play. If they want to undo that action, they'll need a different button.

When a screen reader user hears "link", they'll expect to be navigated to another page and they'll expect the browser's "back" button to take them back to the previous page (unless the page opens in a new tab, which is a separate accessibility consideration).

Comment: This is true even if it wasn't tagged with accessibility. Screen reader users will be as confused as other users when a button behaves like a link and a link behaves like a button.

Comment: Nope, this is wrong, you can set the button's [ARIA role to `link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/link_role) if I'm not wrong and that will allow the screen reader properly identify an element.

Comment: @KitangaNday You are correct that you are wrong. While you could add a `role` to override the default semantics, [rule #2 of ARIA usage](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#second) says to not do that. Just use a real link. Also, setting the role does not give you any **behavior**. By default, a button allows both `enter` and `space` to activate it. A link only allows `enter`. By specifying `role=“link”`, that does **not** prevent the `space` key from activating the “link “.

Comment: @slugolicious, what these specs advise is not always followed, look at when a tags were used as buttons. Also your argument of space being used, why would a user hear "this is a link" and then press space , come on man

Comment: @KitangaNday Not sure how you code, but I follow specs, especially accessibility specs. If you want to treat them as "suggestions" instead of specs, that's your prerogative, but you should be very careful giving out advice that go against accessibility standards.

Comment: @slugolicious all I'm saying is that it's an imperfect world we live in, you'll find things in an interesting situation, these are your best chances for a good user experience. I'd rather give the user the best experience possible than follow a spec word for word. Users over technology.

Comment: @KitangaNday I think you’re missing the point. The whole purpose for the specs is to give the user a better experience. You are going to exclude a large number of users by not following the specs and thus not being accessible.

Comment: @slugolicious how would using ARIA attributes be ruining UX? If you find a repo where it's just not feasible for engineering to make certain changes or production to test a large collection of changes at the time, do what you must to make the user experience better.

Comment: *"how would using ARIA attributes be ruining UX"*.  Easy, websites that have ARIA are more likely to have accessibility issues, mainly because people using it don't understand how it's supposed to work. This is based on research. See the "[ARIA](https://webaim.org/projects/million/#aria)" section of the [WebAIM Million Analysis](https://webaim.org/projects/million). It says *"Increased ARIA usage on pages was associated with higher detected errors. The more ARIA attributes that were present, the more detected accessibility errors could be expected. "*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it depends on how you've set up your buttons.

**TL;DR: since most buttons in CSS libraries are actually `button` elements and a good number of new single page applications use ReactJS and subsequently React Router, you can say that the buttons used to navigate using react-router are behaving like links, since they use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).**

See, historically, almost all buttons were actually `a` tags with a lot of styling to give them the required look. The problem with using `a` tags is when you try to use them as buttons instead of as links. Since a button doesn't necessarily need to link to anything but can perform an action. Well if you skip setting the `href` attribute in an `a` tag, [*fun*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510353/4831083) can be had. This is why you'll notice that some buttons add `#` to the link, this was to stop the *fun* that was experienced when you left out the `href` attribute.

Now, most CSS libraries have transitioned to using the `button` element most probably to avoid all the fun that occurs with using `a` elements as buttons.

Now given that a lot of web applications are put together ontop of [ReactJS](https://react.dev/) and ReactJS uses React Router for single page routing (changing the link without actually causing the browser to reroute you to that link), we can say that the buttons being used to "link" to other pages are links. But in truth they are buttons running javascript that does the routing.

Comment: Cool answer, and I learned something new. But I'd contend the statement "Most web applications use ReactJS." Most web applications are actually developed using PHP and jQuery, by far ;)

Comment: @Devin I'm struggling to put together an argument, thanks bootstrap and wordpress :D

Comment: well, on the bright side, WordPress is slowly moving to full React, Gutenberg blocks are built in React

Comment: @Devin, yep, I had so much hope for this, I think one of the reasons most the devs I know stay away from WordPress is cause of PHP

Answer (score 2):

Appearance of button can change from case to case. Based on your situation you can take decision using Secondary action buttons as link.

For example, Back button. Also attaching one sample widget I designed, where I used secondary action button as link (looks like a link).[image]

Comment: Nice example. That builds on my answer where I suggested that buttons should be actions. "download report" and "re-check score" are actions. The fact that they are styled differently is ok. One should **not** choose a link (<a>) for "re-check score" just because the styling for the link is the visual you want. One should use a real <button> and then style it to de-emphasize the CTA.